# How should I set up run-time external resources in my project?

Tags: visual-studio, project

I'm creating a command line program that uses a defined set of external files (.txts and the like) at runtime. I need it to have these in its working directory when run. Currently, I have them in a folder in the solutiondir with an xcopy into the projectdir as a pre-build event. What's the "accepted" way to set up a situation like this?

Answer (score 1):

If its a .net project then you can mark those files are copy to output directory.
in c++ land (vcproj) you need to use the Pre/Post build step and copy them into the $(TargetDir)/$(ProjectDir)